# Filter count(*) over certain number?

Tags: hive, count, where-clause

If I try to run either of the queries below then I get the message:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 5:0
>   missing EOF at 'where' near 'nino_dtkn'

Which suggests to me that I can't use the newly created count variable in the same query.

Is my conclusion correct?

What can I do to fix it?

I don't want to create a new table - I want to use this as a subquery to merge onto a second table.

```
select count(*) as cnt, 
                   [variable 1]
from [source table]
group by [variable 1]
where count(*) >= 20; 

select count(*) as cnt, 
                   [variable 1]
from [source table]
group by [variable 1]
where cnt >= 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [HAVING](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-HAVINGClause) clause

```
select count(*) as cnt,[variable 1]
from [source table]
group by [variable 1]
having count(*) >= 20;
```

Comment: Thank you VK, your expedience and sagacity are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried, but: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Yep, to add conditions on aggregates, use the having clause! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your expected results . `WHERE CLAUSE`  should always come before `GROUP BY FUNCTION` .

So your query can be rewritten as the one mentioned below :

```
select count(*) as cnt,[variable 1]
from [source table]
where count(*) >= 20
group by [variable 1]
;
```